# Partial fraction with complex roots

Tags: partial-fractions

Is it so that partial fractions with complex roots can work sometime, and sometime not?

I have tried to check a result by WA [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=partial%20fraction%20calculator&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22ApartCalculator%22%2C%20%22rationalfunction%22%7D%20-%3E%22%28104z%2B30%29%2F%28z%5E2%2B4z%2B5%29%22), and tried to solve it manually:

\begin{equation}
X(z)=\frac{104z+30}{z^2+4z+5}=\frac{A}{(z-2+i)}+\frac{B}{(z+2-i)}
\end{equation}

But I get that A does not exist: $(A\cdot 0)=104i-238$ which is false. So B equally does not exist.

Wolfram alpha does not give any solution either.

Is there something important to note when one has complex denominators?

Thanks

Comment: You should have $\dfrac{A}{(z+2+i)}+\dfrac{B}{(z+2-i)}$.  How did you get $0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $z^2+4z+5=(z+2+i)(z+2-i)$, you should search for numbers $A$ and $B$ such that$$\frac{104z+30}{z^2+4z+5}=\frac A{z+2+i}+\frac B{z+2-i}.$$But, since$$\frac A{z+2+i}+\frac B{z+2-i}=\frac{(A+B)z+(2-i) A+(2+i) B}{z^2+4z+5},$$you simply solve the system$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}A+B=104\\(2-i)A+(2+i)B=30.\end{array}\right.$$You will get that $A=52-89i$ and that $B=52+89i$.

Comment: Thanks, I see the error now!